# Pass a string from a User Form Button Click to Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created a UserForm that takes a list of open PowerPoint files and lets a user select which one they want to use.  When they click the 'Set PowerPoint' button, I want to pass that button to a VBA Module where I will set the PowerPoint to the one the user just selected.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UserForm Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public SelectedPPT As String

Private Sub cmdCloseForm_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.RowSource = "Array"
End Sub

Private Sub setPPT_Click()
    'Not sure if this is the best way to select the ppt the user has chosen?
    SelectedPPT = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

This is what the UserForm looks like:
[image]

Then how can I take SelectedPPT and pass it to the module so I can select that specific PowerPoint?

Comment: `function PassPPT(strSelectedPPT as string)......end function` using like `PassPPT(me.combobox1.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SelectedPPT` is breaking *encapsulation* and can be set from outside the form, not just the form's code. You can mitigate this design issue by making the field `Private` and exposing a `Property Get` procedure for it:

```
Option Explicit
Private SelectedPPT As String

Public Property Get SelectedFile() As String
    SelectedFile = SelectedPPT
End Property
```

Set the `ComboBox` row source in the form's `Initialize` or `Activate` handler, so it's initialized once. Then assign `SelectedPPT` when the selection changes in the ComboBox - that's your `ComboBox1_Change` handler.

That removes the need for that [Set PowerPoint] button and its `Click` handler.

I would have an [Ok] and a [Cancel] button, and I'd make the form remember whether it's cancelled:

```
Private IsCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = IsCancelled
End Property

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    IsCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

And then you also need to account for the case where the user clicks the red X button to close the form; you can do that by handling the forms' `QueryClose` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        IsCancelled = True
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

The rest of the logic belongs to the calling code - let's say the form is called `MyAwesomeForm`; you'd have something like this:

```
Dim filename As String
With New MyAwesomeForm
    .Show
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        filename = .SelectedFile
        'do whatever you wanted to do with that filename
    End If
End With
```

Note:

- At no point the form calls `Unload Me`
- It's the caller's responsibility to create *and* destroy the form object
- Caller uses a `New` instance of the form every time
- Caller has read-only access to whatever values the form exposes through properties